# Printing values within an object

Tags: java, object

I've created a margherita pizza. I want it to store some values, such as a few ingredients and its cost. I'm trying to print off the values but I'm getting `null` values back.

However I have noticed if I remove the marg.setCost and just use setCost, it works as I wanted it to. But I thought if I created a marg object I should keep the values in the marg object. I've had a lot of coffee and I'm confused :(

Comment: Please show us your code for all `getIngredientX()` and `setIngredientX()` functions.

Comment: Why is your pizza of Type string?

Comment: It is String because i'm using a string from the scanner, I tried to make it less complex instead of putting String pizza = whichPizza(); which returns a string, I just put margherita, but forgot to put it in quotes on here, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

still now you are using

```
public void margherita(){
PizzaMenu marg = new PizzaMenu();

marg.setIngredient1( "tomato" );
marg.setIngredient2( "basil" );
marg.setIngredient3( "mozzerella" );
marg.setCost( 5.7 );
marg.setBase( "thin" );
marg.setPizza("margherita");

}
```

but you need to use

```
public void margherita(){

setIngredient1( "tomato" );
setIngredient2( "basil" );
setIngredient3( "mozzerella" );
setCost( 5.7 );
setBase( "thin" );
setPizza("margherita");

}
```

the reason behind this is you are creating new object ans assign value to that object. since those data member are not static so that they will not change your obejct (**u**) value.

Answer (score 1):

In the function margharita you are creating another pizzamenu and setting the properties of that object.Your have not set the properties of original object. So you are getting null.But you need to set the properties of the "this" object. Change the below function:

```
public void margherita(){

        setIngredient1( "tomato" );
        setIngredient2( "basil" );
        setIngredient3( "mozzerella" );
        setCost( 5.7 );
        etBase( "thin" );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exactly matches your code but if it does look at

```
public void makePizza(){
    String pizza = margherita;
}
```

That is not a String and so the variable pizza is assigned a null value. Try enclosing it in quotes like

```
String pizza = "margherita";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
    public void makePizza(){
        String pizza = margherita;

        if( pizza.equalsIgnoreCase("margherita")){
            setPizza("margherita");
            margherita();
        }
    }
```

notice that lone call to `margerita()` - this means that you are creating a *separate* Pizza object, which you then simply discard. You can still access the pizza attribute since you set it, but the other ones are never set. You need to explicitly invoke the various set methods in order to store the ingredients for the pizza you are currently working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void margherita(){
    PizzaMenu marg = new PizzaMenu();

    marg.setIngredient1( "tomato" );
    marg.setIngredient2( "basil" );
    marg.setIngredient3( "mozzerella" );
    marg.setCost( 5.7 );
    marg.setBase( "thin" );

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   PizzaMenu u = new PizzaMenu();
   u.makePizza();
   u.print();
}
```

Maybe because your instantiating the PizzaMenu  object class twice..."new PizzaMenu()"
One is in the Main method and one is in the margherita() method...

If that is the way you want to process your code..You can Either create a overloaded contructor for your object class PizzaMenu that will set the values again..

For ex.

```
PizzaMenu(String ingredient, String ingredient2, ..etc..){
/*Do the setters here..*/
}
```

but actually this is not a good programming constructs...Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think it's scope issue.  In `margherita()` you are creating new obj.  But in `print()` you're calling current obj values. The values set to new obj `marg`.  So try to print

```
public void print(){
System.out.println( String.format( "Good choice! You picked the " + "%s", getPizza() ));
System.out.println( String.format( "The " + "%s" + " is made with " + "%s" + ", " + "%s" + " and " + "%s", marg.getPizza(), marg.getIngredient1(),marg.getIngredient2(), marg.getIngredient3() ) );
System.out.println( String.format( "And the price is a very reasonable £" + "%.2f", marg.getCost() ));
```

}

Maybe marg obj not visible to `print()`.  Try to send than obj as an argument!

Comment: I tried that but as the object is created in a different method, when I tried to print marg.getCost() it tells me marg cannot be resolved to a type/variable :(

Comment: Hi,Because marg's scope at ends with in margherita().Try to declare marg in global or send marg Obj as  argument to print function..!

Comment: tell me one thing from where will you call print function??